# Simplistic method for proving inequlaities

Tags: inequality, optimization

I have noticed that many inequalities posed in olympiads or otherwise were solvable using Lagrange Multipliers. However, the method might get tedious in which case, I had noticed that in inequalities involving commutative functions, we can directly obtain the bounds by equating the variables and using the constraint to obtain the value.
If $$f(x,y,z)\geq0$$
was to be proved, subject to some constraint $g(x,y,z)=q$, then I found that by equating $x,y, $and $z$, i.e, $g(x,x,x)=q$, and solving for $x$, and substituting it in $f$, we obtain the inequality. This procedure might not always work correctly, but by placing certain conditions on $f$ it might.

My question is what are those conditions?

Comment: There are very general inequalities of which many contest problems are particular cases that have those characteristics. For example, Muirhead's inequality. Now, as those inequalities become common knowledge of students they start to disappear from competitions. Then you see inequalities that do not fit into that scheme.

Comment: @RGB But aren't there any $common$ criteria for $f$ i.e the function to be optimised in the general inequalities. I thought of convexity but then couldn't prove it.

Comment: As a side note, if you use Lagrange Multiplies (calculus) at competitions, they become extremely strict, and require you to check all of the conditions (about differentiability, boundary conditions, local extrema etc.) Often, if you proof is missing any small gap, you get 0 immediately, 1 if everyone is feeling very generous.

Comment: @AnuragPallaprolu Yes, there are cases. In general, I think that studying the inequalities of symmetric functions is still subject of research. Names to search for are Muirhead's, Newton's, Shur's inequalities.

Comment: @CalvinLin I hope that only happens in some competitions. Hopefully only bad and unimportant ones. To have such a bias for certain techniques only limits students in what they learn, and that is not the goal of competitions. Asking the problems to always have an elementary solution is a different thing. That helps to ensure that students having advanced knowledge don't have unreasonable advantage.

Comment: A better way to make them not use Lagrange is to design problems in which Lagrange gets nasty quickly, and that is not so hard.

Comment: @RGB Sorry, should have added a caveat. It happens at the IMO, which has an explicit distaste for calculus approaches. Of course, the undergrad competitions like Putnam and IMC require the use of calculus. I mentioned this because OP started off with "olympiads"

Comment: That happens at IMO? That is such distasteful. I don't see the point of it. It is like instead of placing the burden on the committee to make sure the problems are nicely designed to not have trivial solutions using calculus, they punish the students that have studied additional content. So, a calculus solution that is almost done wouldn't get a $4$?

Comment: @RGB The IMO believes in getting math students who don't use calculus extensively. I too hate that feature. Also, do all convex functions f exhibit this property?